# Reset admin password of OpenVAS

Tags: debian, openvas

When I installed OpenVAS, I was prompted for a password, however the prompt errored out. I have installed OpenVAS and it is working properly, however I cant get in as admin (I created a new user and that works fine).

I've tried googling how to reset admin password, recover admin password, change the access of a user to admin, but to no avail.

Greenbone Security Assistant is version 4.0.
OpenVAS is version 6 I believe (I just installed it today)

Host OS is Kali Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE: This was the solution several years ago and this answer, although accepted, is now outdated. Please look at other answers to find an up to date solution**

You can create a new administrative account with :

```
openvasad -c add_user -u your_new_login_here -r Admin
```

Then use this account to change the default admin's password.

Comment: Not sure why this comment is accepted but the command is not even existing.

Comment: This answer is from 6 years ago and seems to be out of date now. I have just edited it to indicate that, I hope it's the correct way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 55):

Try this:

```
openvasmd --user=admin --new-password=new_password
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Just stop openvas before doing it, especially if it's running scans.

Comment: Agree, this should be the accepted answer. Upvoted for more attention. Also, this command would update an existing user called 'admin' with a new password. Run `openvasmd --get-users` to list all users.

Comment: Apparently, OpenVAS is being renamed to Greenbone Vulnerability Management (GVM) so `openvasmd` has been changed to `gvmd`.

Answer (score 7):

To change the web login :

```
openvasmd --create-user NEWUSER
```

It will automatically generate a password for the new user.

Use this new account to modify the admin password.

To remove the 'junk / false' account just enter

```
 openvasmd --delete-user=NEWUSER
```

or do so in the WebUI.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux Mint you simply run "sudo /usr/sbin/openvas-adduser" and follow the prompts. A blank rule set